# Sort an array from right to left without using default functions

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I was reading about arrays and I'm wondering how can I sort the elements from an array from right to left.

For example:

```
n = 10
numbers = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    numbers.append(i)
print(numbers)
```

How can I show the components from the last one to the very first one (10, 9, 8...) using basics tools like cycles and conditions?.

And besides this alternative:

```
    for i in range(-1, (-len(numbers) - 1), -1):
        print(numbers[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't sorting an array. You are attempting to construct one with a particular ordering. You can do this using `range` directly. `range` can be invoked with three arguments `start`, `stop` and `step`. This allows you to construct a range `10, 9, ...`:

Python 2:

```
numbers = range(10, 0, -1)
print numbers
```

Python 3:

```
numbers = list(range(10, 0, -1))
print(numbers)
```

output

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Use `list` directly in python3. `numbers = list(range(10, 0, -1))`

Comment: I'm speaking about Py3 here. The `list` is a builtin function 1. Lesser code and easier to use than Listcomp 2. More readable. 3. Much faster

Comment: Aha. Looks better now. Thanks. For the reference part - You can test it out on your system.

Comment: Run these two in your terminal `python3 -m timeit "numbers = [i for i in range(10, 0, -1)]"` and `python3 -m timeit "numbers = list(range(10, 0, -1))"`

Comment: Thank you, this works for me :). Although I thought that it could be somehow possible using the "i" to compare with something and get the same result...

Comment: @BhargavRao I had tried with ipython but the results weren't very robust. Too much scatter, potential caching effects and so on.

Comment: True that they are scattered variations. But I have written a script to retest that 10,000 times and on the aggregate the `list` call fared better.

Comment: @Xcecution If this answer fixes your issue, do accept it ([click the check mark next to the appropriate answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)). That does three things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist and you get rewards too. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: I don't really understand the downvotes, to me this question is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` with `reverse=True`

`sorted(numbers, reverse=True)`

or try `list.sort`  method

`number.sort(reverse=True)`

But in your case you simple can use reverse indexing

`number[: : -1]`

Comment: Im looking for a solution not using default functions.

Comment: then in your case you can use reverse indexing. I show that in my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have list in reverse you could do this:

```
In [17]: [4,6,7][::-1]
Out[17]: [7, 6, 4]
```

Comment: `range(1, 11)[::-1]` In python2 you are creating 2 lists for no reason.

Comment: Use `list(range(1, 11)[::-1])` in Python3.

Answer (score 1):

```
list(reversed([1,2]))
>> [2,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different algorithms to sort arrays without default functions. Here's a list of some of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm. You can use a sorting algorithm to sort the array, then, reverse it using `reversed(list)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `range` function for that, like

```
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    print(number[i])
```

If you want to reverse your list in descending order then you can use the `sort` method of lists.

```
number.sort(reverse=True)
```